# Android GitLab runner CI using Docker with KVM return INFO: Your CPU does not support KVM extensions

Tags: android, docker, continuous-integration, gitlab, kvm

Hi I am trying to enable KVM in Android GitLab runner using Docker

Docker command

```
docker run --privileged -d --name gitlab-runner --restart always -v /srv/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest
docker run --privileged --rm -it -v /srv/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner gitlab/gitlab-runner register
```

YML file

```
  - apt-get --quiet install qemu-kvm libvirt-daemon-system libvirt-clients bridge-utils --yes
  - apt-get --quiet install cpu-checker --yes
  - kvm-ok
```

but it return failed

```
INFO: Your CPU does not support KVM extensions
KVM acceleration can NOT be used
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

is it possible to enable KVM using Docker in Android GitLab CI?